# Filling a path with a particular color

Tags: objective-c, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext

I want to fill a path with red. This is my code:

```
CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextBeginPath(c);
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 10, 10);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 20, 20);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 20, 40);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 40, 20);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 10, 10);
CGContextStrokePath(c);
CGContextFillPath(c);
```

I know that I have to use `CGContextSetFillColor()` and `CGContextFillPath()`, but it's not working.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to attempt to fill the path?

Comment: @craig sure, i edit first post

Comment: solved. answer in first post.

Comment: Please don't add "(solved)" or answers to the question; post your solution below, as an answer. This is both allowed and encouraged when you have resolved the problem yourself.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @craig: If you look at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10339653/revisions) (click the "edited N hours ago" link) you'll see it.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau But unless I'm mistaken, your edit removed his 'solved' version of code, leaving only the original section of code that doesn't work?

Comment: @craig: Yes, because the answer should be put below, in the answer section, not in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer in my case is:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//set fill pattern
UIColor *patternRed = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patternRed.png"]];

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, patternRed.CGColor);

CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, self.frame.size.height);
for (int i = 0; i<255; ++i) {
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, stepX*arrayX[i], self.frame.size.height - (arrayYRed[i]*stepY));
}
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, stepX*255, self.frame.size.height);
CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGPathRelease(pathRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set a line width on the above example, so here's a sane example that will draw a line down the left hand side of a rect. Taken directly from a drawRect function

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGFloat gray[4] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, gray);

// left
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, CGRectGetHeight(rect));

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift use :

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(context)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I thought that the question is asking for the right method for changing the fill color so these are the 2 simple lines of code (pretty self explanatory by the way) ?? What should i need to explain ?